# Interactive calendar using Java

Tags: java, calendar, interactive

I'm new to java and need to build a hotel Management System using Java. There I want to include interactive Calendar/ Event planner (Something like Google Calender) to keep record of future bookings and functions. I have no idea how to do it. Are there any libraries which are helpful? Or else how can i do it? Please help me... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem** and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Also, what technologies are you using? Is it SWT/Swing desktop app, is it web app? Depends on what is it, you are using different libraries.